# PHP and JavaScript Buttons not working?

Tags: php, javascript

My code (Below) works in Internet Explorer, but not in Chrome, Safari or Mozilla Firefox. Not sure why, but would it be possible for someone to point me in the right direction? This code has some buttons which change the form's action attribute and direct the data to different PHP controller file to do different things such as create user, modify user etc

**JavaScript code:**

```
<script language="javascript">

function formAction(flag) {
    switch (flag){
        case "create": 
            document.forms.useraction.action = "/apps/portal_admin/create_user1.php";
            break;
        case "modify":
            document.forms.useraction.action = "/apps/portal_admin/modify_user1.php";
            break;
        case "copy":
            document.forms.useraction.action = "/apps/portal_admin/copy_user1.php#user2";
            break;
    }
    document.forms.useraction.submit();
}
function helloworld() {
    alert("Hello World");
}
</script>
```

**PHP code:**

```
<?php
    if ($authlib->auth_authobj($posting_userid,$_COOKIE['shost_app_id'],'002')>=2) {
        echo "<input type=\"button\" value=\"Create User\" class=\"formButton\" name=\"create\" id=\"create\" onClick=\"formAction('create')\">\n";
        echo "<input type=\"button\" value=\"Copy User\" class=\"formButton\" name=\"copy\" onClick=\"formAction('copy')\">\n";
    }
    if ($authlib->auth_authobj($posting_userid,$_COOKIE['shost_app_id'],'002')>=3) {
        echo "<input type=\"button\" value=\"Edit User\" class=\"formButton\" name=\"modify\" onClick=\"formAction('modify')\">\n";
        echo "<input type=\"button\" value=\"This button works\" class=\"formButton\" name=\"Working\" onClick=\"helloworld()\">\n";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Clean up your code first and narrow it down to the actual problem in it's simplest form. Also, using a framework like jQuery might help solve your crossbrowser problems.

Comment: So you're saying the "Hello World" function and alert work in all the browsers, but the `formAction()` function only works in IE? Do you get any error messages in the console? Have you tried putting an `alert()` or `console.log()` before and after the `switch` statement and after the `submit()`? That would at least tell you if the function is even being called and if it is breaking part-way through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you have only one form on page. Your code has two errors.

**1**
To solve your problem, change all

```
  document.forms.useraction.action
```

to

```
  document.useraction.action
```

**2**
Also note that formAction is a reserved handler. You can not use formaction as a function name. Change the function name to formActionz or something else:

```
function formActionz(flag)
```

Answer (score 0):

Following on from TheNoble-Coder's answer it might be better to restructre your code as follows:

```
var actions = {
    'create': '/apps/portal_admin/create_user1.php',
    'modify': '/apps/portal_admin/modify_user1.php',
    'copy':   '/apps/portal_admin/copy_user1.php#user2'
};

function formHandler(event)
{
    var target = window.event.target || window.event.srcElement,
        form = document.forms['useraction'];

    form.action = actions[target.name];
    form.submit();
}
```

**fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/AmmTZ/

#### jQuery

If your using jQuery, you can use the following code and avoid using `onclick=` on elements

```
$(function() { // Shorthand for $(document).ready

    $('[name=create], [name=modify], [name=copy]')
    .click(function() {
        $('form[name=useraction]').prop('action', actions[this.name]);
    });

});
```